# adding current time to ambiguous date using momentjs

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm currently using FullCalendar and need to add the current time to an ambiguous date moment in the select callback function.

When selecting a day in month view, the callback function parameters "start" and "end" return an ambiguous date (no time) moment. I'm using the following to add the current time to the date then convert it back to a moment but wonder if this is the proper way to do it...

```
if(!start.hasTime()){
    start = moment(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'+' '+ moment().format('HH:mm:ss')));
      end = moment(  end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'+' '+ moment().format('HH:mm:ss')));
}
```

As you can see, I'm converting the "start" and "end" dates and current time moments into strings then converting the concatenated string back into a moment.

I want to make sure that the moment i'm creating is in valid ISO 8601 format.

Thanks,
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In the [official docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) says if you call `format()` function you get the date in ISO 8601 format.
check this out: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h7sxxnnj/)

Furthermore, if you dont want to handle the timezones, you can use the `utc()` [method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, strangely when I upgraded to fullcalendar v3.40. According to [fullcalendar docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/),
the `format()` and `toISOString` functions have been overridden within fullcalendar for ambiguously timed moments to return dates only i.e. '2017-03-06'. To overcome this and set a time, you need to create a new moment object which is what you have done. To ensure consistent parsing across browsers though, you should specify the format you are parsing as recommended by [moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/). So for your scenario, it will be:

```
    if(!start.hasTime()){
        var format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';
        start = moment(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'+' '+ moment().format('HH:mm:ss')), format);
        end = moment(  end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'+' '+ moment().format('HH:mm:ss')), format);
    }
```

To make the code cleaner and easily readable though, you could create a new moment using the unix timestamp (which is a number and doesn't rely on string formats) of the `start` moment and set the time using the moment `set` function. So it could now look like this:

```
    if(!start.hasTime()){
        var timestamp = start.valueOf();
        var now = moment();
        var startMomentWithNowTime = moment(timestamp).set({
          'hour': now.hour(),
          'minute': now.minute(),
          'second': now.second()
        });
        start = startMomentWithNowTime;
        end = startMomentWithNowTime;
    }
```

Excuse the descriptive variable naming `startMomentWithNowTime`. A few more lines but hopefully easier to read. You could also wrap this logic in a function to use on demand. Hope it helps!